# Pandas - Go through 2 columns (latitude and longitude) and find the distance between each coordinate and a specific place

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame (called coordinates) containing 3 columns: index, Latitude, Longitude - it has roughly 1,000 rows. I have the coordinates of a specific place and want to find the distance between the place and all the coordinates in the data frame. Currently, I can use geopy.distance to find the distance between two specific coordiantes. E.g.

```
import geopy.distance
site_coords = (38.898556, -77.037852)
place2_coords = (38.897147, -77.043934)
print(geopy.distance.vincenty(site_coords, place2_coords).km)
```

The above code gives 0.5503161689006362 (I have checked and this is correct)

My issue is with looping through the data frame (called coordinates) and calculating the distance for all coordinates in that data frame. Currently, this is what I have:

```
import geopy.distance
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('coordinates.csv', sep=',', header=None)

site_coords = (38.898556, -77.037852)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    place2_coords = df
    x = geopy.distance.vincenty(site_coords, place2_coords).km
    print(x)
```

However when i print x it prints the same distance many times and the distance is incorrect. The coordinates file looks something like (when opened in notepad) - but has many more rows:

```
,Latitude,Longitude
0,73.3645,-0.9015
1,73.3645,-0.3995
2,73.3645,-0.5825
```

So i need a way to loop through and find the distance.

Comment: Your loop is calculating the distance between `site_coords` which is defined outside of the loop and `tile_coords` which is defined somewhere, but definitely not within the loop. So your loop is just calculating the same thing over and over. Did you mean to have `place2_coords` in the calculation of x?

Comment: yes sorry, tile_coords is meant to be place2_coords. Yes so i need place2_coords to change and be all the values in the coordinates file @ALollz

Comment: according to the documentation https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html?highlight=vincenty#module-geopy.distance vincenty is deprecated, are you aware?

Comment: Oh, i wasn't I will change that, thanks @Yuca. but i still need to find a way to loop through the whole coordinates

Comment: are the columns of the dataframe 'Latitude' and 'Longitude' only?

Comment: Well when I open it in notepad it appears to have 3 columns (one sort of index just counting up) but let me open it in excel and see. @Yuca

Comment: Just in case `vincenty` does not work, you could use: `geopy.distance.distance` (after adding this line at the top of your code: `import geopy.distance`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

couple of things, first you are asking for the distance between a tuple and a dataframe, and I'm not sure how that works. However, the following loop should work for you under the assumption that the dataframe `df` only has two columns

```
site_coords = (38.898556, -77.037852)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if index > 0:
        x = geopy.distance.vincenty(site_coords, (row[1],row[2])).km
        print(x)
```

Comment: I get this error: ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values. The data frame does contain 3 rows, is the only way to do this is try and remove the first row as the first row is not needed,

Comment: is the first row filled with nans? since I don't have the data I can't replicate your specific conditions and it sounds like your csv has an empty row somewhere

Comment: No, my data shouldn't have any Nans, the first row is just filled with increasing numbers which aren't at all useful. DO you know how i could delete this column and try and run your code again?

Comment: I get a different error this time -  ValueError: Location based indexing can only have [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array] types.

Comment: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Yes it prints out this                                                                                              
0         24
1    72.3645
2     0.9185

Comment: It prints 0, 1, 2 in a vertical line and 24, 72.3645, 0.9185 in a vertical line next to this

Comment: it prints: 72.3645

Answer (score 4):

See here a variation on the one of  [sechilds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1325117/sechilds). The `site_coords` are an input to the def. The apply function now uses 2 arguments: the `row` from the DataFrame and `site_coords`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import geopy.distance

def calc_distance(row, site_coords):
    station_coords = (row['lat'], row['lon'])
    d = geopy.distance.distance(site_coords, station_coords).km
    return(d)

df['distance'] = df.apply(calc_distance, site_coords=(38.898556, -77.037852), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `iterrows` method will give you a `pandas.Series` object for each row of the data frame, so you can create the `place2_coords` a bit differently.

```
import geopy.distance
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('coordinates.csv', sep=',')

site_coords = (38.898556, -77.037852)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    place2_coords = (row.Latitude, row.Longitude)
    x = geopy.distance.vincenty(site_coords, place2_coords )).km
    print(x)
```

With pandas, looping of the rows isn't the recommended method. Instead, you can apply a function along the columns.

```
def calc_distance(x):
    site_coords = (38.898556, -77.037852)
    place2_coords = (x.Latitude, x.Longitude)
    return geopy.distance.vincenty(site_coords, place2_coords )).km
df.apply(calc_distance, axis = 1)
```

Comment: When i run the iterrows method i get this error AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'Latitude'. Also in the second method, you pass x into the function is this the dataframe?

Comment: I receive the same error for the other method aswell

Comment: The errors are because of the `header=None` when the csv file is read. I will edit that.

Answer (score 2):

If your file looks like

```
,Latitude,Longitude
0,73.3645,-0.9015
1,73.3645,-0.3995
2,73.3645,-0.5825
```

but you read with "head=None",

```
df = pd.read_csv('coordinates.csv', sep=',', header=None)
```

the first line will become a data row instead. This may be the reason why you get a "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'Latitude'.".

Try deleting "header=None" from your code.

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep=',')
site_coords = (38.898556, -77.037852)

df.apply(lambda row: geopy.distance.vincenty(site_coords, (row.Latitude, row.Longitude)).km, axis=1)
```

Comment: Yes that was the issue thankyou. It is the apply which is the important part that goes through all the columns. Also what is the purpose of lambda?

Comment: Nothing special. Sorry for the confusion, the code I posted is just what I typed for test -- and I wanted to type less. sechilds's answer is definitely better.

Comment: This may seem like a very noob question but is the series ordered if i put x = df.apply(lambda row ..... will the first item in this be for the first coordinates in my file?

Comment: Yes,  the order is preserved.